# Why the session data item changes its value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, session

I am developing a web page in asp.net mvc. In an action, the controller recives an object, it stores the object's values in an item of the session, and then passes it as parameter to a method that stores the object in another variable and after some validations can modifies the variable's values. The problem that I have is that once the method changes the values of the variable, for any reason that I don't know the values in the session item change as well.

Does anyone know why the data in the session item change and how can I achive that don't change?

Here the code of the action and of the method:

```
<AllowAnonymous()>
Function ListadoArticulos(ByVal filtroArticulos As Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios, Optional iPage As Integer = 1) As ActionResult
    Dim filtroOriginal As Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios = CType(Me.Session.Item("filtroArtListaOriginal"), Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios)
    Dim filtroLista As Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios = CType(Me.Session.Item("filtroArtLista"), Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios)
    ViewBag.iIdTipoBien = 5
    ViewBag.iValue = New SelectList(orderListItems, "iValue", "sDescripcionValue", filtroArticulosNew.iOrdenLista)
    ViewBag.filtrosAplicados = Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios.DepurarFiltroAnuncioArticulo(filtroOriginal, filtroLista)
    Return View(listaAnuncios.ToPagedList(iPage, 27))
End Function


Public Shared Function DepurarFiltroAnuncioArticulo(ByVal filtroOriginal As      Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios, ByVal filtroAplicado As Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios)
        Dim filtroResultado As New Capturas.FiltrosArticulosAnuncios
        filtroResultado = filtroAplicado

        'Evalúa el valor de cada propiedad del filtro y actualiza la propiedad en el caché
        If filtroOriginal.iIdPais > 0 Then
            filtroResultado.iIdPais = Nothing
            filtroResultado.Pais = Nothing
        End If
        If filtroOriginal.iIdCategoria > 0 Then
            filtroResultado.iIdCategoria = Nothing
            filtroResultado.Categoria = Nothing
        End If
        If filtroOriginal.iIdTipoOperacion > 0 Then
            filtroResultado.iIdTipoOperacion = Nothing
            filtroResultado.TipoOperacion = Nothing
        End If
        If filtroOriginal.iIdUnidadPolitica > 0 Then
            filtroResultado.iIdUnidadPolitica = Nothing
            filtroResultado.UnidadPolitica = Nothing
        End If
        If filtroOriginal.lPrecioDesde > 0 Then
            filtroResultado.lPrecioDesde = Nothing
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(filtroOriginal.sDescripcionArticulo) Then
            filtroResultado.sDescripcionArticulo = Nothing
        End If
        Return (filtroResultado)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because how session persistence work and object reference work. If you put an object to the session wrapper, it's not persisted right away but at the end of the asp.net pipe-line. You only pass a reference to an object when you place it in the session wrapper. By the time it starts serializing the session the object had already changed.  I'd suggest putting a cloned object to the session wrapper. Implementing [IClonable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) interface or using the [Object.MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method

Comment: Thanks ! That is the answer. I just implemented the ICloneable Interfece, I've created the copy of the object and done, the problem was solved.